# Problemas con el QuickSort al añadir un nuevo elemento

Tags: quicksort

Tengo una lista ordena y añado un nuevo elemento, que es igual a uno que ya existe. Al ordenar la lista otra vez el nuevo elemento es colocado delante del que ya existe y lo necesito detrás. ¿qué hacer? Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Robert. Te invito a pasar por el centro de ayuda para saber [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Necesitaremos saber qué has intentado, en qué lenguaje, qué error estás obteniendo. Saludos

Comment: Es probable que necesites cambiar el comportamiento del *swap*. Tal vez si en vez de comparar `a >= b` lo pongas al revés o quites la igualdad. Dependerá de cómo tengas implementada la función de *swap* y si estás ordenando ascendente o descendente. Sin ver el código es difícil precisar. Saludos